# Assigning cells formula using variable and cell reference

Tags: string, excel, excel-formula, vba

I am trying to assign a formula to a cell whose reference changes at every iteration. The left-hand side of the assignment below, however, seems to work since if I make the right-hand side "=""Test""", it seems to work.

I guess the problem then is with my formula on the right hand side. There is a combination of strings, a variable that changes with each loop iteration and a value taken from a cell.

```
    Worksheets("LimsOutput").Cells(4, 2 + 14 * i).Formula = "=" & BR & " Blah blah " & Worksheets("Lims").Range("A3").Value
```

I'm thinking that the problem may be to do with the quotes in the sheet and cell referencing.

Comment: Did you try debugging it? What is the value of `BR` and `Worksheets("Lims").Range("A3").Value`

Comment: BR is just a string whereas the value in A3 is a date.

Comment: Ok So what output (lets say for a moment) are you expecting with the above code?

Comment: If BR is say the string "STRING" and date 30/06/2012, the output I would like in the cell is STRING Blah Blah 30/06/2012

Comment: Perfect... And what exactly are you getting?

Comment: I get runtime error 1004. I have a feeling I'm not using quotes correctly and that I ought to be using double-quotes for the sheet and cell references..

Comment: Ok posting and answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A concatenate formula in an Excel cell would look like this in your case

```
 = "String" & " Blah Blah " & "30/06/2012"
```

To convert that into code, use `CHR(34)` for double quotes and `"&"`

See this example

```
Worksheets("LimsOutput").Cells(4, 2 + 14 * i).Formula = "=" & _
                                                        Chr(34) & BR & Chr(34) & _
                                                        "&" & _
                                                        Chr(34) & " Blah blah " & Chr(34) & _
                                                        "&" & _
                                                        Worksheets("Lims").Range("A3").Value
```

One more thing :)

`Worksheets("Lims").Range("A3").Value` will give you `0.00248508946322068` for `30/06/2012`

So the above code will give an output like `STRING Blah blah 0.00248508946322068` To get the date in the end you have to add `CHR(34)` before and after the date as well. For example

```
Worksheets("LimsOutput").Cells(4, 2 + 14 * i).Formula = "=" & _
                                                        Chr(34) & BR & Chr(34) & _
                                                        "&" & _
                                                        Chr(34) & " Blah blah " & Chr(34) & _
                                                        "&" & _
                                                        Chr(34) & Worksheets("Lims").Range("A3").Value & Chr(34)
```

Comment: That works perfectly! Thank you - just one thing the date format is coming through in decimal but when I try to make the following correction '"& TEXT(" & _
                                                        Worksheets("Lims").Range("A3").Value & _
                                                        "," & Chr(34) & "dd-mmm-yy" & Chr(34) & _
                                                        ")"' The date comes out as 00-Jan-00...

Comment: Refresh the page :) I have already mentioned that in the above post ;)

Comment: Ok thanks just read above edit! Many thanks for your help and patience :)

Answer (score 0):

Below is a simple example. I hope this helps you.

```
 Sub sample()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("B1:B" & lastRow)

    Dim BR As String
    BR = "STRING"

    rng.Formula = BR & " Blah blah " & cstr(Range("$A$3"))

End Sub
```

[image]